# Check if an ITypeSymbol is a delegate type

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

How can I check if an `ITypeSymbol` instance refers to a delegate type (like `Action` or `Func<T>`).

I think I can check if the base type is `System.Delegate`. Is this the correct way to do so or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check its [`TypeKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.itypesymbol.typekind?view=roslyn-dotnet):

```
typeSymbol.TypeKind == TypeKind.Delegate;
```

Comment: I swear I checked `TypeKind` and it wasn't there when I looked :(